# I need help in ActionScript3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a time limit game, but when I load the game and it passes the time limit that is placed it reaches zero but it is not directed to the next scene where I have the game over .. this is the code that is placed

```
var tiempo:int;
var Duracion:int;


Duracion = 7;
tiempo = Duracion;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,Duracion);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fin)
timer.start();


function tiempo2(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace(tiempo);

    tiempo--;

    time.text = tiempo.toString();

}

function fin(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = tiempoevent.target as Timer;
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2)
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fin)


}
```

How do I get you to the game over scene ... I'm working on animate cc

Comment: No hablamos espanol aqui.

Comment: si hablas español T-Heron y sabes de actionscript3 ayúdame que no se English

Comment: English maybe translate?

Comment: I pass to english you can help me please

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 function fin(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
 {
     var timer:Timer = tiempoevent.target as Timer;
     timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2);
     timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fin);
     nextFrame();
 }
```