# I need time limit help in ActionScript3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a time limit game, but when I load the game and it passes the time limit that is placed it reaches zero but it is not directed to the next scene where I have the game over .. this is the code that is placed

```
var tiempo:int;
var Duracion:int;


Duracion = 7;
tiempo = Duracion;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,Duracion);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fin)
timer.start();


function tiempo2(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace(tiempo);

    tiempo--;

    time.text = tiempo.toString();

}

function fin(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = tiempoevent.target as Timer;
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2)
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fin)


}
```

As I do to be directed to the Scene of game over ... I am working on animate cc ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Necesito ayuda en ActionScript3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201497/necesito-ayuda-en-actionscript3-0)

Comment: you must edit previous Question not posting new one for small changes, the previous post was edited, so you know how to Edit them!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because You have wrote two identical questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201497/i-need-help-in-actionscript3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Timer ends, `fin` function will be executed.
Just add this line to go to another Scene:

```
function fin(tiempoevent:TimerEvent):void
{
    var timer:Timer = tiempoevent.target as Timer;
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tiempo2);
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, fin);

    gotoAndPlay("GameOver", 1);
}
```

Here is full code simplified:

```
var duracion:int = 7;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, duracion);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerFin);
timer.start();

function onTimerTick(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    var timeLeft:int = timer.repeatCount - timer.currentCount;

    time.text = String(timeLeft);
}

function onTimerFin(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerFin);

    //go to scene named "GameOver" on frame 1
    gotoAndPlay("GameOver", 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for me yet `gotoAndPlay("GameOver", 1);`

Comment: Why? What happens? It looks like your don't start the timer, do you see trace(tiempo) when it runs?

Comment: Check my improved answer. Also at line: `timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fin)` it should be `.TIMER_COMPLETE` not `.TIMER`.

Comment: Maybe GameOver scene has more frames and it keeps playing, if yes, try `gotoAndStop()` ?

Comment: Now no error:
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label GameOver not found in scene GameOver.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at bolafinal_fla::vCam_7/onTimerFin()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Even if I put it that way:
`gotoAndPlay(1,"GameOver");`

or
`gotoAndPlay("GameOver" ,1);`
Always gives me the same error

Comment: Has mail to send you a copy of the game I'm working on adobe animate cc, if not no problem I'm new in actionscript3.0

Comment: Gracias ya me funciono... Bendiciones
Translate:
Thanks, I'm working .... Blessings